# Show that a sentence that has no sentence letters is either a tautology or a contradiction

Tags: logic

Show that if a sentence *φ* of L<sub>1</sub> contains no sentence letters, then *φ* is either a tautology or a contradiction. Use Lemma c, which states that:

> If *A*(P) = *B*(P), for every sentence letter P in *φ*, then |*φ*|<sub>*A*</sub> = |*φ*|<sub>*B*</sub>

My attempt:

Towards a proof by contraposition, we can suppose that *φ* is not a tautology and *φ* is not a contradiction. This means that *φ* does not receive the same evaluation under all structures, or rather |*φ*|<sub>*A*</sub> ≠ |*φ*|<sub>*B*</sub>.

This is where I'm stuck: I'm tempted to say that if |*φ*|<sub>*A*</sub> ≠ |*φ*|<sub>*B*</sub>, *φ* must contain sentence letters (whereafter I could say that *φ* *must* contain sentence letters in order to receive different evaluations by different structures--this will have proved the contraposition). But this doesn't seem true -- constants can also have different evaluations under different structures.. is this the wrong strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the formula φ contains no sentence letters, then φ is either ⊤ or ⊥ or a truth-functional combination of them with connectives, like e.g. ⊤ → ⊥.

But ⊤ and ⊥ are sentential constants, in the sense that they have the same truth-value in every truth-assignment, i.e, for every A and B we have that A(⊤)=B(⊤) and A(⊥)=B(⊥).